# Sql Where Statement

Tags: sql, blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to compare two variables that I'm getting from json service with a database that I have in my app. I tried to hard coding it and it worked

```
Statement st = tmsDB.createStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM ObjectTexts WHERE programID ='AAA' AND objName ='BBB'");
```

But when I tried to do this `

```
Statement st = tmsDB.createStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM ObjectTexts WHERE programID="+ JsonProgramID  +"AND objName ="+JsonobjName);
```

it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
FROM ObjectTexts WHERE programID='"+ JsonProgramID  +"' AND objName =' "+JsonobjName +"'"
```

If you observe the hardcoded query your parameters are inside single quotes, but dynamic one missing single quotes.

In SQL all String/Varchar should be inside single quote.

Note: These raw queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection.

The BlackBerry API supports the normal create, prepare, bind, execute semantics:

```
Statement st = tmsDB.createStatement( "SELECT * FROM ObjectTexts WHERE programID=? AND objName = ?");
st.prepare();
st.bind(1, JasonProgramID);
st.bind(2, JsonobjName);
Cursor c = st.getCursor();
...
```

Comment: If his queries are highly vulnerable to SQL Injection, could you show him the proper way to avoid it, then?

Comment: @X-Zero: I don't know much about blackberry API that is why I didn't suggest. In android this is how you need to do http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html

Comment: @thinksteep good answer, I took the liberty of editing in some BlackBerry API code. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the answer. Your answer is very accurate and right on the point!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing spaces and single quotes. Try this:

```
 Statement st = tmsDB.createStatement("SELECT * FROM ObjectTexts WHERE programID= '"+ JsonProgramID  +"' AND objName = '"+JsonobjName+"'");
```